# Transform a SU(2) matrix into exponential form

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, unitary-matrices

I have the following $SU(2)$ matrix
$$U(\mu,\theta,\phi)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i \mu } (\cos (\mu )-i \cos (\theta ) \sin (\mu )) & e^{i \varphi } \sin (\theta ) \sin (\mu ) \\
 -e^{-i \varphi } \sin (\theta ) \sin (\mu ) & e^{-i \mu } (\cos (\mu )+i \cos (\theta ) \sin (\mu )) \\
\end{array}
\right). \tag{1}$$
And I am thinking how to transform this matrix into the exponential form
$$U=\exp(-i(a_1 J_1+a_2 J_2+a_3 J_3)), \tag{2}$$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are free real parameters, $J_1,J_2,J_3$ are $SU(2)$ generators. In our case, in fundamental representation, $J_i=\sigma_i/2$, so we can expand this as
$$
\begin{aligned}
&U=\exp(-i(a_{1} {\color{red} J_{1}}+a_{2} {\color{red} J_{2}}+a_{3} {\color{red} J_{3}})) \\
&=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right)-i x_{3} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right) & (-x_{2}+(-i) x_{1}) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right) \\
 (x_{2}-i x_{1}) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right)& \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right)+i x_{3} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
$$
where we have defined $\vec{a}=a \vec{x}$, $\vec{x}$ is a unit vector and $a=||\vec{a}||$. (According to comment 1)

Since $SU(2)$ matrix is connected and compact, we can always able to write it into eq.(2). But I find it's really hard to transform eq.(1) into (2). Can anyone give me some advices?

I've tried that if the $e^{i\mu}$ and $e^{-i\mu}$ are disappeared in (1), the conversation from (1) to (2) is straightforward, $a_{1}\to -2 \mu  \sin (\theta ) \sin (\varphi ),a_{2}\to -2 \mu  \sin (\theta ) \cos (\varphi ),a_{3}\to 2 \mu  \cos (\theta )$. However, I am puzzled how to obtain $a_1,a_2,a_3$ from original (1).

Comment: To make the matrix more readable, it may be a good idea to write $\vec{a}=a \vec{x}$ where $\vec{x}$ is a unit vector and $a=\|\vec{a}\|$. Then the upper-right entry is $\cos(a/2)-i x_3 \sin (a/2)$ which is substantially easier to parse.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for your advice, I'll do that!

Comment: To make this even nicer, one can write $$U=\exp(-i a (x_1 J_1+x_2 J_2+x_3 J_3))=\cos\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\sigma_0-i (x_1 \sigma_1+x_2 \sigma_2+x_3 \sigma_3) \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$$ where $\sigma_0=\mathbf{1}$. So figuring out $a_1,a_2,a_3$ amounts to expressing $U(\mu,\theta,\phi)$ as a linear combination of Pauli matrices.

Comment: After looking at this some more, it seems like it's not -terrible- to compute $(a,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ if $(\mu,\theta,\varphi)$ are known. (The worst of those is $a$, which can be seen by computing the trace of both expressions for $U$. But once $a$ is known, the $x_k$ are reasonably simple functions of $(\mu,\theta,\varphi,a)$.) Going the opposite direction, by contrast, seems quite miserable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help identifying (1) with (3).

By taking the sum and the difference of the diagonal entries, and, separately, of the off-diagonal ones, you have the four equations,
$$
\cos{a\over2}= 1+\sin^2\!\mu~(\cos\theta -1),\\
x_3 \sin{a\over2}=\sin \mu \cos\mu ~ (\cos\theta -1 ),\\
x_1 \sin{a\over2}= -\sin\phi \sin\theta\sin\mu,\\
x_2 \sin{a\over2}=-\cos\phi \sin\theta \sin\mu.
$$

Note, crucially, squaring both sides and adding you get 1 on both sides!

So you have *a* from the first equation,
$$
a= 2 \arccos \left [ 1+\sin^2\!\mu~(\cos\theta -1) \right ],
$$
whence its sine,
$$
\sin{a\over2}= \sqrt{1-\cos^2{a\over2}}=...
$$
whence  $\hat x$ from the other three...

Comment: One way to make this look slightly nicer is to $x_1=r\sin\phi$, $x_2=r\cos\phi$. Then the latter two conditions become $r \sin(a/2)=-\sin \mu$. Similarly, one can rearrange the first two equations to write $x_3=\tan \mu \tan \frac{a}{4}$. This at least makes the substitutions for $a$ slightly less tedious.